# how to append a dropdown list from viewbag in javascript

Tags: javascript, razor, append, dropdown

I am trying to create a append function using javascript . The way i want it to work is when i click on add button the entire div should replicate with incrementing the id .
i am able to create it with text box but when i introduce dropdown as viewbag in the append html code i  am getting error

the below is my js code

```
 var m = 1;
        var h3label = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".add_info").click(function () {

                $("#sibs").append(`
                                  <div class="border-5">
                                      <h3>Insurance Dependent (${h3label++}) </h3>
                                              &nbsp;
                                              &nbsp;
                                              &nbsp;
                                  <div class="row mb-2">
                                       <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dependent Name <span style="color:red;font-size:20px">*</span></label>
                                       <div class="col-sm-3">
                                       <input asp-for="InsuranceNomiee1Name" class="form-control" placeholder="James" id="Milname" required readonly />
                                       <span asp-validation-for="InsuranceNomiee1Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                                       </div>

                                  </div>
                                  &nbsp;
                                  &nbsp;
                                  <div class="row mb-2 ">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Relationship With Dependent <span style="color:red;font-size:20px">*</span></label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <select asp-for="InsuranceNomiee1Relationship" class="form-control" id="insrel" asp-items="$@ViewBag.relationship" readonly>
                                                </select>
                                                <span asp-validation-for="InsuranceNomiee1Relationship" class="text-danger"></span>
                                        
                                        </div>
                                  </div>

                                  </div>
                         &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                `);

            });
        });
```

this is my html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="sibs" class="row mb-2 "></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-info ml-2 button-icon rounded-small add_info"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add </button>


        </div>
    </div>
```

please guide

Answer (score 0):

You could create JS variable in Razor.

```
var viewBag = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag));
```

and it will let you use that variable as you wish.